# What's the best way to keep adding new points to glBufferData?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am making an experiment with OpenGL to find what's the best/most efficient way to very frequently add new data to glBufferData.

To do this, I wrote a small 2D paint program and simply keep adding points when I move the mouse.

The whole function looks like this:

```
void addPoint(double x, double y)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pointVertBuffObj);
    if (arrayOfPointCapacity < numOfPoints + 1) {
        U32 size = (arrayOfPointCapacity + 8) * sizeof(Point2);
        Point2 *tmp = (Point2*)realloc(arrayOfPoints, size);
        arrayOfPoints = tmp;
        arrayOfPointCapacity += 8;
    }
    arrayOfPoints[numOfPoints].x = x, 
    arrayOfPoints[numOfPoints].y = y;
    U32 offset = numOfPoints * sizeof(Point2);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numOfPoints * sizeof(Point2), arrayOfPoints, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    numOfPoints++;
}
```

Having to reset glBufferData with new data each time I add a point seems absolutely crazy. I thought about using `glBufferData` to allocate a large array of points and setting these points up with `glBufferSubData`. When the size of the buffer becomes too small, then I call `glBufferData` again increasing the size of the buffer, and copying back existing points to it.

Ideally, I would prefer to avoid storing the point data in the computer memory and keep everything in the GPU memory. But when I would resize the buffer, I would have to copy the data back from the buffer to the CPU, then resize the buffer, and finally copy the data back to the buffer from the CPU. All this, also seems inefficient.

Any idea? What's best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When the size of the buffer becomes too small, then I call glBufferData again increasing the size of the buffer, and copying back existing points to it.

Not a bad idea. In fact that's the recommended way of doing these things. But don't make the chunks too small.

> Ideally, I would prefer to avoid storing the point data in the computer memory and keep everything in the GPU memory.

That's not how OpenGL works. The contents of a buffer objects can be freely swapped between CPU and GPU memory as needed.

> But when I would resize the buffer, I would have to copy the data back from the buffer to the CPU, then resize the buffer, and finally copy the data back to the buffer from the CPU. All this, also seems inefficient.

Correct. You want to avoid copies between OpenGL and the host program. That's why there is in OpenGL-3.1 and later the function [glCopyBufferSubData](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glCopyBufferSubData.xml) to copy data between buffers. When you need to resize a buffer you can as well create a new buffer object and copy from the old to the new one^1.

---

[1]: maybe you can also do resizing copys within the same buffer object name, by exploiting name orphaning; but I'd first have to read the specs if this is actually defined, and then cross fingers that all implementations get this right.

Comment: You have a source for "resizing buffers is the recommended way of doing these things"?  Or is it your recommendation only?  (Not a bad thing, since you are an expert)

Comment: Great answer (as usual thx). Now, I don't understand your second comment "it's not how OpenGL works". yes it can be swapped using something like glMapBuffer, I guess that's what you mean, but the process seems inefficient. Now I like your third option (glCopyBufferSubData) but then you'd potentially get two big buffers at once while you do the copy: the old one and the new one with the right size. If both are large, then as I said, the GPU has to manage them both, until the copy is done, at which point the first buffer can be freed. I don't know about orphaning. Sounds interesting.

Comment: @BenVoigt: It's not so much a OpenGL recommendation, but one of the well established practices in implementing paged memory allocators. I hereby refer to the vast amount of publications on the topic of memory allocators. In the end it boils down to the fact, that every OpenGL object may get swapped to the host memory. So the effective memory chunk granularity (which is what your program "feels") is the greater of the host system page size or the GPU paging size. Even if the GPU pages are much smaller, because memory transactions happen on the host page level, this is what you get in the end.

Comment: Oh, one more thing: Because in OpenGL everything happens through indirect handles and objects can be swapped as needed, the allocation of a new object may as a side effect trigger a compactification run, that rearranges objects already in GPU memory to make space for the new object. The details are not specified and each implementation does it as it sees fit best.

Comment: @user18490: The problem with any kind of allocation resize operation is, that between the original allocation and the resizing, new allocations may have been done, that "snugly" surround it. In some environments you can get away by managing your data in a linked list (though for reasons of efficiency, such list based architectures will also have some kind of bulk array internally). Now when it comes to swapping, well: OpenGL always employed a virtual memory model. Textures, PBOs, VBOs, Renderbuffers, at any time they may be copied to host memory, if GPU memory is low.

Comment: @user18490: More importantly though, modern GPUs treat their local memory like a cache. For example since a few GPU generations it's possible to have textures, with more data than what can fit into a GPUs available memory. Instead the relevant portions of the texture get swapped in only when required. In combination with sparse texture support (i.e. some regions of the texture are marked as not populated with data) this allows to have very large textures (several 10k or more pixels in each direction) and as long as only a small subset is used nothing has to be swapped.

Answer (score 3):

I made a program for scientific graphing before, that could add new data points in real-time.  What I did was create a fairly large fixed size buffer with flag `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW`, and added individual points to it with `glBufferSubData`.  Once it filled, I created a new buffer with flag `GL_STATIC_DRAW` and moved all the data there, then started filling the `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` buffer again from the beginning.  So I ended up with a small number of static buffers, one dynamic buffer, and since they were all equal size (with monotonically increasing x coordinates) calculating which buffers to use to draw any given segment of the data was easy.  And I never had to resize any of them, just keep track of how much of the dynamic buffer was used and only draw that many vertices from it.

I don't think I used `glCopyBufferSubData` as datenwolf suggests, I kept a copy in CPU memory of the data in the dynamic buffer, until I could flush it to a new static buffer.  But GPU->GPU copy would be better.  I still would allocate more chunk-sized buffers and avoid resizing.